# How to sort an entire file on a specifc data/column?

Tags: python

[data.txt]

```
CODE\tUSERNAME\tSPENT\tCOLUM1\tCOLUM2
```

I want to sort the file [data.txt], using "SPENT". How can i do this?

Comment: you could use `split()` or regex `re`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. For example:

```
# read file into array of lines
lines = open("data.txt").readlines()

# sort those lines using a lambda
lines.sort(key = lambda line : line.split("\t")[2])
```

The lambda extrudes the `SPENT` column from the row to be used as sorting-key.

Comment: What? Only this??? *.* Trying...

Comment: Spent will turn on List? Dictionary? Array? I need to do the 

for (line in text): ?

Comment: `read()` reads the entire file content into the string `text`. I split it into an array at tabs(`\t`) and assigned the 3rd element (index 2) to the variable `spent.` `spent` is a string. This is very basic stuff though...

Comment: Sorry for this... my professor dont teatch me the basic to do the question that i'm doing here..

I have some space in my throughts, here in there...

Comment: Now i understand what the query want's...It's a sort in file using a specific column =/

Comment: I hardly understand what you try to tell me. Spaces? You can get rid of leading and trailing whitespaces with `.strip()`: `spent = text.split("\t")[2].strip()`

Comment: Ah! I understand! Give me a second to edit my answer

Comment: edited it in! untested, but that should do the trick

Comment: Any Suggest to "sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[0]))"?

Comment: Felk, sorry for the "Spaces"... i mean that i have some problems with python because my teatcher do not explain the basic before give us a query/question...

Comment: def subMenu_5():

 # read file into array of lines
 lines = open("database").readlines()

 # sort those lines using a lambda
 lines.sort(key = lambda line : line.split("\t")[2])

 sortUP = open("sortUP","w")
 for i in range (3):
  sortUP.write(lines[i])
 sortUP.close()

This work!

Answer (score 0):

```
 def subMenu_5():

    # read file into array of lines
    lines = open("database").readlines()

    # sort those lines using a lambda
    lines.sort(key = lambda line : line.split("\t")[3])

    clientList = []
    dataQuantify = 0
    database = open('database','r')
    i = 1
    while (i == 1):
        if (database.readline() == ''):
            i = 0
        else:
            dataQuantify = dataQuantify + 1
    database.close()


    sortList = open("sortList","w")
    for i in range (3):
        sortList.write(lines[i])
    sortList.close()

    print "[Código] [Nome] [Quant. Prod. Comprados] [Valor Gasto] [Descontos] \n"
    sortList   = open('sortList','r')
    i = 0
    while (i < dataQuantify):
        clientList.append(sortList.readline())
        print clientList[i]
        i = i + 1
    database.close()
    raw_input("Precione 'ENTER' para voltar ao menu principal... ")
    return
```

This work! Very Thx!